# Asynchronous call handling

Tags: java, spring

I have a rest API endpoint for creating and updating. But both are calling an asynchronus service. Means api's give instant response to caller.

If the update call comes before the creating call, how can I handle this on an asynchronus service?

NB : I am using Spring MVC

Comment: If the update call comes before the creating call? This makes no sense to me since why do you call update on something that isn't created? Would be nice with some code examples or further explanation.

Comment: Some multithreaded worker thread picks the api calls from a queue and call my API's. If one thread picks create call then other will pick update call. And then for some reason like network delay or other things update call comes first and then create call comes

Comment: Make it as synchronouse service.

Comment: If you use websockets/stomp you can send a response back to the client indication what happened at the end of the asynchronous operation.